# Screen is black on PC startup

Tags: display, troubleshooting

I have a Dell desktop and when I try turning it on, the screen is black and all I hear is a few beeps. Can someone help me find the problem?

Comment: Is it black *all the time*? Does the screen turn on? Did you try another screen?

Comment: Are the beeps different from what your normally hear?  More beeps, less?  Different tones?  If they are the same then check all the cables to make sure they haven't become loose, is there power to the monitor?  Does the monitor's light turn on?

Comment: When i turn on the computer the screen is black and the monitor light turns on but then its starts making beeping noise 6 beeping. and then it just stops but i hear the moitor working. yeah i tried another screen and its black.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem is being detected by the ROM during startup, and an [POST error code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) is being generated by your laptop. This is usually a problem with your motherboard or memory.

Without knowing which model of laptop you have and which sequence of beeps you're having, the best I can do is point you to your support manual, which is also accessible online at http://support.dell.com.

Answer (score 0):

If bios worked then ur using Windows and your video driver is wrong or not at alls installed or u reinstalled it to wrong one.
Try after bios loading pressing F8 many times till ull get asked to start Windows different ways. Take last good known windows configuration mode. It may work if does then from now it it will work again till next time Windows messed up.
I recomend ubuntu its free and no viruses couse its linux.
see ubuntu.com
u can try it live mode from cd or from usb without installing.